# entity framework proxy retrieve Id only

Tags: entity-framework

I am working with EF6 and have 2 objects which are linked together (A has B).  When i query A (byId), a proxy object for B is retrieved.  When I access properties of B, the proxy object is 'expanded' and retrieved entirely from the database.

However the only property i need to have is the Id of B (in order to serialize it from my API).  Is there a way to tell EF to not load the entire object if the requested property is already in memory?

Comment: You want too much from EF. If you need granular control of loaded properties, use projection and DTOs.